# 'Value' element in <select>

Tags: html

Is there a case where the value is used in the Select tag as below?

```
<select name="cars" id="cars" value="dream_cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Nothing founded the value do

Comment: The documentation is right here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attributes. There is no `value` attribute. What exactly did you want or expect it to do, especially considering you've used a value that does not appear in your options list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, the  element does not have a value attribute that is used to pre-select an option. The selected option is determined by the selected attribute within the  element

Incase if you want to preselect, you can add 'selected' attribute in option.

```
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes" selected>Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it doesn't have a `value` **content-attribute**, it does have a `.value` *IDL attribute* though, that you can use to set the selectedness of the <option> children.